# Increase and decrease value in Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a very simple carousel with **Pure Javascript and CSS**. I'm having trouble with the **"next" and "previous"** button, since they should communicate the with each other, setting the **current position of the carousel**.

Here is my current code (or JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbumjLw2/1/):

```js
// Slider

var listRecommendations = document.getElementById('list-recommendations');
listRecommendations.style.left = 0;

// Previous button
document.getElementById("btn-prev").onclick = function() {
  // Making sure this functions will not run if it's the 0px of the slider
  if (parseInt(listRecommendations.style.left) != 0) {
    var currentPosition = parseInt(listRecommendations.style.left) + 100;
    listRecommendations.style.left = currentPosition + 'px';
    console.log(currentPosition);
  };
}

// Next button
var num = 100;
var maxValue = 1000 + 120;
console.log(maxValue);

document.getElementById("btn-next").onclick = function() {
  if (num < maxValue) {
    num += 100;
    listRecommendations.style.left = '-' + num + 'px';
    console.log(num);
  };
}
```

```css
#list-recomendations{
  position: absolute;
}

.wrap-items .item{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="recommendation">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="list-recommendations" class="wrap-items">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Slider controls -->   
  <button id="btn-prev" class="btn-slider prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="btn-next" class="btn-slider next" title="Ver mais sugestões">Next</button>
</div>
```

As you can see on the console, the **next button** increases "100" at each click, and the **previous button** decreases "100" at each click. The previous button seems to be working fine, but the next button don't get the updated value, it always increase using the latest value it used.

**Expected result:**

Next button clicked: 100 > 200 > 300...

Prev button clicked: 200 > 100 > 0...

Next button clicked: 100 > 200 > 300...

**Current result:**

Next button clicked: 100 > 200 > 300...

Prev button clicked: 200 > 100 > 0...

Next button clicked: 400 > 500 > 600...

Any idea on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: add some result what is happening and what you are expecting?

Comment: a better title would be "... without using a framework or external libraries". All JavaScript code is "pure"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/kbumjLw2/2/)

```
// Previous button
    document.getElementById("btn-prev").onclick = function() {
        // Making sure this functions will not run if it's the 0px of the slider
            var currentPosition = parseInt(listRecommendations.style.left) - 100;
            listRecommendations.style.left = currentPosition + 'px';
            console.log(currentPosition);
    }

    // Next button
    var num = 100;
    var maxValue = 1000 + 120;
    console.log(maxValue);

    document.getElementById("btn-next").onclick = function() {
        if (num < maxValue) {
            var currentPosition = parseInt(listRecommendations.style.left) + 100;
            num = currentPosition;
            listRecommendations.style.left =  num + 'px';
            console.log(num);
        };
    }
```

you basically need to take the `left` value each time and do plus (`+` next) minus (`-` prev) on it.

Comment: Thanks. That's almost perfect. On the line "23", I need it to set the value in negative. So on each click should result on.. "-100", "-200", "-300". If I add a minus signal on this line, it enters on a loop between 100 and 0. Any idea? Here's a updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbumjLw2/6/

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro You don't need to add minus signal on that line since arithmetic is already done on two lines before that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no use of `num` as you can play with the current position of the element.

Also note, `-` will concatenate the `-` symbol the the value, it will not subtract the value.

Ty this:

```js
var maxValue = 1000 + 120;
var listRecommendations = document.getElementById('list-recommendations');
listRecommendations.style.left = 0;
document.getElementById("btn-prev").onclick = function() {
  var val = parseInt(listRecommendations.style.left);
  if (val != 0) {
    val -= 100;
    listRecommendations.style.left = val + 'px';
    console.log(val);
  };
}
document.getElementById("btn-next").onclick = function() {
  var val = parseInt(listRecommendations.style.left);
  if (val < maxValue) {
    val += 100;
    listRecommendations.style.left = val + 'px';
    console.log(val);
  };
}
```

```css
#list-recomendations {
  position: absolute;
}
.wrap-items .item {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="recommendation">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="list-recommendations" class="wrap-items">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Slider controls -->
  <button id="btn-prev" class="btn-slider prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="btn-next" class="btn-slider next" title="Ver mais sugestões">Next</button>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kbumjLw2/5/)

Comment: Thanks, that's almost the same approach from @gurvinder372. It works just fine, but if I try to set the new value as negative, it creates a loop between 100 and 0. Check this comment with a fiddle example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077428/increase-and-decrease-value-in-pure-javascript/35077575#comment57877371_35077502